# Sharing DataContext to UserControl in a type safe way

Tags: silverlight, user-controls, datacontext

I'm developing my first Silverlight 4 app and are struggling on how to to share my DataContext set on the top element (a Grid) in my MainPage.xaml into an underlying UserControl, in a type safe way. The DataContext is an instance of my ViewModel class and my thought is to be able to bind certain elements in the UserControl to properties of the ViewModel.

I am pretty sure the ViewModel object bubbles down to my UserControl but how can I in the UserControl asure that the DataContext is of type PatternCreatorViewModel?

Hope this was understandable!

Comment: Why would you want to that?  Think about the answer to that question carefully.

Answer (score 6):

This is (in my lonely opinion) one of the biggest limitations of the data binding model in Silverlight and WPF, namely, that there's no type safety anywhere in the process.  As soon as you type {Binding...} you're working without a net.  MS managed to take a wonderfully glorious strongly-typed language like C# and tied it to a completely non-type-safe data binding model, thereby all but wrecking a decade of Anders Hejlsberg's wonderful work on C#.  You expect this sort of "looseness" when working with dynamic languages, but not when you're dealing with C#.

This limitation really becomes problematic when you're changing the ViewModel underlying your Views, because of course, there's no easy way to test your data bindings.  Normally, when you've got code that you can't test, you can at least rely on the compiler to tell you if what you're asking the code to do doesn't make any sense.  But because MS made data bindings non-type-safe, not only can you not test your changes, you can't even rely on the compiler to tell you when they don't make any sense.  And, to add insult to injury, you can't even rely on running your application and seeing if you get any error messages: because bindings always fail silently.  The best you can do is turn up the logging level and walk through tons of debug error messages.  Uggh.  Nasty as hell.

See my blog posting [here](http://blog.wouldbetheologian.com/2009/07/why-wpf-databinding-is-awful-technology.html), another question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197054/strongly-typed-databinding-in-wpf-silverlight-xaml), and my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154171/wpf-silverlight-programmers-is-mvvm-overkill/3154299#3154299) for more thoughts on the underlying issue.

I should note that I seem to be virtually alone in my opinion about this one, so perhaps there's something huge that I'm just missing.  But I personally think you've hit the nail right on the head.

Comment: I'd be interested in what the API and Xaml syntax that is type safe would look like?

Comment: I've given that some thought, but clearly not enough :-).  My suspicion is that it would act a little like C# generics.  When you declared your object in XAML, you would specify the type that it expects to bind to, i.e., <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" x:DataContextType="MyViewModel" />.  If you didn't want type checking, you'd just leave that attribute blank, but if specified, any objects assigned to the data context would be checked to make sure they were an instance of that type, and any data bindings you specified would be checked to confirm they would work with that type.

Comment: You're not alone :P Same goes with previous version of Entity Frameworks include paths - at least that got fixed in the latest versions. So hopefully someday the binding in WPF will ge better, too... (by the way, of course binding is type-save, you just can't define the type of the DataContext and have to work with custom DependencyProperties)

Answer (score 0):

**Pleasd see update below: the first proposed solution may cause threading-issues.**

One possibility is creating a `DependencyProperty` of the required type, updating that during `DataContextChanged` and binding to that.

**DefaultEditor.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class DefaultEditor : UserControl 
{
    public DefaultEditor()
    {
        this.DataContextChanged += OnDataContextChanged;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetValue(propertyNameProperty, this.DataContext as IPropertyProvider);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty propertyNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(PropertyProvider), typeof(IPropertyProvider), typeof(DefaultEditor), new PropertyMetadata(default(IPropertyProvider)));

    public IPropertyProvider PropertyProvider
    {
        get { return (IPropertyProvider)GetValue(propertyNameProperty); }
    }
}
```

Note: I reduced the standard Visual Studio pattern for the DepenendencyProperty, because I did not want a public setter.

Also, make sure to add the event handler *before* calling `InitializeComponent()`.

**DefaultEditor.xaml:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.DefaultEditor" x:Name="self">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=self, Path=PropertyProvider}">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Index}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Once `x:Name="self"` is defined I have Intellisense for `Path=PropertyProvider` and the other bindings.

Note: Be sure not to set the entire control's `DataContext` (which would be recursive), use another (top-level) element like the `Grid`.

And, in case it wasn't obvious: In the example above `IPropertyProvider` is a custom type that must be replaced with the required type.

**UPDATE:**

While the above does work, it can invite code to access `DefaultEditor.PropertyProvider` from a wrong thread (other than the element's dispatcher's thread), which leads to an `InvalidOperationException`. This can be resolved by replacing the `DependencyProperty` with a simple property and implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Here's an updated code-behind, the .xaml remains the same.

**DefaultEditor.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class DefaultEditor : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public DefaultEditor()
    {
        this.DataContextChanged += OnDataContextChanged;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyProvider = this.DataContext as IPropertyProvider;
    }

    private IPropertyProvider _propertyProvider;
    public IPropertyProvider PropertyProvider { get => _propertyProvider; private set => SetField(ref _propertyProvider, value); }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Note: The `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation is a Visual Studio (Resharper?) code-snippet.

Using this code, `DefaultEditor.PropertyProvider` can be accessed from any thread.